# Permission bit manipulation query

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have the following tutorial question in regards to bit manipulation and permissions, i dont quite understand. Specifically B as i understand it >> 3 operand is a bitshift of 3 spaces but that would result in all zeros for a bit protection of type... |0000400| >> 3 00000000|4 ...?

```
// File types
#define S_IFDIR (0040000)      // Directory
#define S_IFREG (0100000)      // Regular file
#define S_IFLNK (0120000)      // Symbolic link
// Protection bits
#define S_IRUSR (0000400)       // Read by owner
#define S_IWUSR (0000200)       // Write by owner
#define S_IXUSR (0000100)       // Execute by owner
#define S_IRGRP (S_IRUSR >> 3)  // Read by group
#define S_IWGRP (S_IWUSR >> 3)  // Write by group
#define S_IXGRP (S_IXUSR >> 3)  // Execute by group
#define S_IROTH (S_IRGRP >> 3)  // Read by others
#define S_IWOTH (S_IWGRP >> 3)  // Write by others
#define S_IXOTH (S_IXGRP >> 3)  // Execute by others
```

Note that above constants are in octal, not decimal or hexadecimal.

For each of the following scenarios, give an octal representation of a bit-string that would capture the relevant privileges:

a.    a regular file that is only readable and writeable to its owner

b.    a regular file that is writeable to its owner, but readable by owner/group/anyone

c.    a regular file that is only executable to owner/group/anyone

d.    a directory that only the owner can read, create files in, or enter

e.    a directory that only the owner can create files in, but anyone can read/enter

f.    a directory that owner/group/anyone can read, create files in, or enter

answers:

a.    0100600

b.    0100644

c.    0100111

d.    0040700

e.    0040755

f.    0040777

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically B as i understand it >> 3 operand is a bitshift of 3 spaces but that would result in all zeros for a bit protection of type... |0000400| >> 3 00000000|4 ...?

`>> 3` is a bitshift of 3 *bits*, not 3 digits. In octal representation, each digit corresponds to 3 bits (8 = 2<sup>3</sup>), so bitshifting by 3 bits would correspond to shifting by 1 digit of the octal representation.

Therefore, `00004000 >> 3 = 00000400` in octal.